# Website Redirect 404 Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to get the website to redirect from non-www addresses to www address, but I'm getting a 404 error. Instead of redirecting from rookmgmt.ca to www.rookmgmt.ca, it shows www.rookmgmt.ca/public_html/ in the address bar, which is where the site is actually placed. Here's what I have written in my .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rookmgmt.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rookmgmt.ca/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also, I should note that the .htaccess file is placed in the root folder on the server, while the site is placed in the /public_html/ folder.

Comment: .htaccess should also be placed in `/public_html/` folder and that should be your `DocumentRoot` as well.

Comment: I copied the file to the public_html folder but I'm still getting the error. Does the DocumentRoot need to be defined in both files or just in the root .htaccess file?

Comment: `DocumentRoot` is set in Apache config files.

Comment: That fixed it, and clearing my browser cache removed the error. Thank you for the help.